# how to include model name in route in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

hello guys i m new to loopback and don't know how i can link or include model in root.js for eg :-

```
   var next = require( '../../common/models/emplyee');
   module.exports = function(app) {
   app.get('/get',next.getemployeee );
   };
```

and in emplyee.js

```
 module.exports = function(Emplyee) {
  Emplyee.getemployeee = function(callback) {
    // TODO
    callback(null,{data:"qwe"});
  };
  };
```

i know i can use this kind of code in express but i want to know how i can use this code in loopback i tried but  it throw error  var next = require( '../../common/models/emplyee'); is this correct way or i missing something

Comment: What is the purpose of the endpoint? There is a good way to do it in loopback way, so you'd be able to add some ACL methods to your endpoint, otherwise you will have to make it by yourself. For example, if you're going to prepare a custom employee endpoint, you can create a remote method on the employee model. Check [this chapter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html) from the docs

Answer (score 0):

@rocky it can be something like this

```
  var next = require( '../../common/models/emplyee');
  var emp=app.models.Emplyee;
  var check=new next(emp)
  module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/get',check.getemployeee() );
 };

  module.exports = function(Emplyee) {
   Emplyee.getemployeee = function() {
     var data="hii";
    return data
  };
  return  Emplyee
 };
i think it not a good way to do. i haven't try but it should work
```